# error: could not lock config file C:/Usersls/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Tags: git, git-bash

When i run `git commit -m "html"` I get error message:

```
error: could not lock config file C:/Usersls/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

[image: error msg]

I have tried to run Git bash as administrator, didn't work. The path `C:/Usersls/` does not exist on my computer, is that the issue? If so how do I change the path of my `.gitconfig` file, where should it be located?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $HOME`?

Comment: /c/Usersls

I have no idea what Userls is, dont have it on my computer

Comment: thats odd, gitbash should have config in their own folder (`..\Program Files\Git\etc`). did you install bash from MinGW/MinSYS or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: I believe MinGW, it says: MinGW64

Comment: Why are you trying to use Git from inside an pretend Linux environment??????? Either use Git from a Windows console, or use WSL. If you want to work on Linux and/or containers, you *must* install WSL anyway. Docker uses WSL to run Linux containers.

Comment: It seems `C:/Usersls/` should be `C:/Users/ls/` instead? Some configuration is borked there. Install Git for Windows instead of using MinGW *or* as suggested try out WSL.